# Change CRM 4.0 selected row color

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I use the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813204/colorize-the-crm-grid) solution on CRM 4 in order to colorize the CRM grid, depending on the values of several fields. It works fine, except the rows are not highlighted with a different color anymore when they are selected.

This is the usual interface:

[image: Usual interface]

This is my interface:

[image: My interface]

Is there anyway to get back the highlight color? And to change it?

Comment: what caused it to stop working?

Comment: @Greg It stopped working as soon as I added the code in the grid.htc file (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10813205/825024)

Comment: Sorry Otiel this fell off my radar - got very busy just after starting to answer this. If you enable script debugging in IE (Press F12 > Script > Start Debugging) then you try to select a row, do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this a bit more, the issue here I suspect is that you are blanket changing the row colour when you initialise the grid. From the [linked] code:

```
if (new_date_value <= current_datetime) {
    InnerGrid.rows[i].style.backgroundColor="ff0066";
} else {
    InnerGrid.rows[i].style.backgroundColor="ff6600";
}
```

My first thought is to colourise only *some* of the columns in the row. Row highlighting would then apply to the rest of the row. This is just a quick lash-together. Further, it is **untested**.

You will get the idea and maybe write this to better to suit your requirements

E.g:

```
var colour1 = "ff0066";
var colour2 = "ff6600";

if (new_date_value <= current_datetime) {
    colouriseRow(InnerGrid.rows[i], colour1);
} else {
    colouriseRow(InnerGrid.rows[i], colour2);
}

function colouriseRow(myRow, cols){
    for(var i = 0; i < myRow.cells.length; i++){
        if(i > 2){ // skip the first 3 columns, colourise the rest
            myRow.cells[i].style.backgroundColor=myColour;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I can't get it to work, I'm not sure why. But anyway, it's not what I would like to do as I want to keep the whole row colorized. Thank you though.