# CRM 4.0: Custom Grid Colour

Tags: javascript, grid, crm

I've just read this post: [Colorize the CRM grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10813204/1480631).

I'm trying to do something similar but I want to be able to change just the font colour of a column called Status Reason.

Will it be possible to modify this code to do this and if yes would someone please be able to point me in the right direction.

I will warn you at the outset that I've only been playing with Javascript and CRM customization for about 2 weeks now!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be possible to modify the code to do that.

If you read the code through, you will see that the "styling" is done near the bottom:

```
if (new_date_value <= current_datetime) {
    InnerGrid.rows[i].style.backgroundColor="ff0066";
} else {
    InnerGrid.rows[i].style.backgroundColor="ff6600";
}
```

So your styling changes would just slot in there.

You will also notice that this bit of code is applying style to the entire row (`InnerGrid.rows[i]...`) whereas you only want to apply it to a specific column within that row, so you would address `InnerGrid.rows[i].cells[colorizeColumn].style...` instead (assuming you will just change the column that is triggering the formatting.

That should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Here's what I've got so far: `var colorizeColumn = InnerGrid.FindColumnIndex("statuscode");
 if (colorizeColumn > 0) 
 {
  for (var i = 0; i < InnerGrid.AllRecords.length; i++)
  {
   if (InnerGrid.rows[i].cells[3].innerText == "To Be Closed")
   { 
    InnerGrid.rows[i].cells[3].style.backgroundColor="ff0000";
   }
  }
 }`  This doesn't seem to work but I'm assuming that's because I'm not referencing the column that I want to change correctly. Any tips? P.S: Apologies for the formatting, I can't seem to insert line breaks for some reason!